# Entity Framework - Migrations on Azure - Real Life Scenario - Downgrading database

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

This has been on my mind for a long time and luckily I have not been in the need of this answer yet, however I would still like to know the best approach. Let's say we have following setup:

- **Web API** built on top of **Entity Framework** (code first) on **Microsoft Azure**.
- **Automatic migrations enabled** (migrates automatically to latest version)
- We have two slots - **Production** & **Staging** (both have separate database)

Let's follow this scenario:

1. We **deploy** a new version to **staging slot** (verify that all is working)
2. Staging database is automatically migrated to latest version
3. We **swap** **staging** instance to **production** slot
4. **Migrations** are **run** on the **production** database
5. We realize - for whatever reason - we need to downgrade and move to previous version.

OK, now come all my questions:

1. How do we downgrade the database to previous version - (since I don't think it is a good idea connecting with VS to production and running the downgrade command from the package manager console).
2. Is the workflow as following: downgrade the database with current instance (which will result in brief downtime of the web app since migrations will not match), then swap the staging slot (old) instance to production slot?

I have been scratching my head with this for a while since I can't see any ideal way how to do this - since the entity framework breaks when the migrations do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of discussion with other developers I came to the conclusion that we have really two choices:

1. Downgrade the database to previous migration through the Azure Portal (the cloud shell command), switch the instances back, close your eyes and pray that all will be good.
2. Safer seems issuing a patch migration or a patch your code and release a new version. Especially since your new code has been already released once it might be wiser to fix it rather than do the reverting game.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an SQL script that will downgrade the database. See the "Getting a SQL Script" section of this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/index#specific

On the workflow, the way we "solve" this is that the current version of the database should support older versions of the application.

Only after a field or table has not been used for several versions, is it actually deleted. There are drawbacks with this approach, the database can get bloated and messy. But it does give the flexibility of being able to install older versjons of the application.

Comment: Thank you for the input - however it doesn't really answer my question - my problem is not adding / removing columns - but seeing how to avoid breaking the application if a migration was already run on the database. Even if I was keeping the columns it still means the EF breaks when there is a migration already applied that it doesn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup at my company and instead of using the code-first migrations we use [Fluent Migrator](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator).  As part of the application start up code, it runs all the outstanding migrations.

Just like any solution you will find you will need to write the Up and Down code so that it knows what to do to upgrade and downgrade.

Comment: Thank you, my problem is not creating migrations but the whole workflow of downgrading a production database without whacking EF that the current model doesn't match the database schema. (meaning that there was a migration already applied before)

Comment: So the problem here is that you essentially have two independent systems that are required to be in line, the application and the database.  To handle this issue you need to version your database schema and version your application.  Luckily through database backups and source control tags you should be able to restore it to a specific point in time without any issues.  

The trouble becomes when you don't want to lose any data added to the database which is why you will need a down migration so it knows how it should undo the changes to the data.